# Salary with vector array to get sum of employee gross pay

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am to create an application that takes at least 5 employees i.d, names, pay rate, and hours. And then I am to add the pay rate and the hours together to show the gross pay for each employee at the end of the initial inquiries. I am stuck on how to add it in the vector please help!

** Here is the assignment that our instructor gave us **

http://itweb.fvtc.edu/ag/?u=3&f=cpp-assignment4

I've added a vector and added all the essential information for the employee

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


struct Employee
{
    int id;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    float payRate;
    int hours;

};


int main()
{
    /*========= other way of adding employee information ==========*/

    /*const int NUM_EMPLOYEE = 5;
    Employee employee[NUM_EMPLOYEE];



    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "ID of employee " << (i + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> employee[i].id;

        cout << "First Name of employee " << (i + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> employee[i].firstName;

        cout << "Last Name of employee " << (i + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> employee[i].lastName;

        cout << "Pay rate for employee " << (i + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> employee[i].payRate;

        cout << "Hours worked " << (i + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> employee[i].hours;
    }*/

    /*========= End of other way of adding employee information ==========*/

    vector<Employee> employees;

    char Another = 'y';

    while (Another == 'y' || Another == 'Y')
    {
        Employee e;
        cout << "Enter employee ID: \n";
        cin >> e.id;
        cout << "Enter employee first name: \n";
        cin >> e.firstName;
        cout << "Enter employee last name: \n";
        cin >> e.lastName;
        cout << "Enter employee pay rate: \n";
        cin >> e.payRate;
        cout << "Enter employee hours worked: \n";
        cin >> e.hours;
        employees.push_back(e);

        cout << "Another? (y/n): \n";
        cin >> Another;

    }

    float sum = 0;

    vector<Employee>::iterator it = employees.begin();

    for (; it != employees.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << "ID of employee:  \n" << it->id << ": \n" 
            << "Employees name: \n" << it->firstName << " " << it->lastName << ": \n" 
            << "Employee pay rate: \n" << it->payRate << ": \n" 
            << "Employee hours worked: \n" << it->hours << "\n";
    }

    float avg = sum / employees.size();

    Employee e;

    /*cout << " ID of employees: \n" << e.id;
    cout << " Name of employees: \n" << e.firstName << " " << 
 e.lastName;*/
    cout << "Gross pay of employees: \n" << avg;







    _getch();
    return 0;

}
```

Show Id, names, and gross pay of all employees to user

Comment: Looks reasonable to me. Could be problems if you accidentally input a string where you needed an integer so I highly recommend testing the stream for successful entry before using any of the values entered,

Comment: Are you specifically stuck on the "gross pay" part?  All you have to do is loop over employees like you are doing to print the employee information, then calculate `it->payRate * it->hours`.  Then you can put that in a new field of `Employee`, or print it, or whatever else you need to do.

Comment: When you print the employees you do not do anything with `sum`.

Comment: See the function `std::toupper()`.  Use it like `if (toupper(Answer) == 'Y')`.  No need for two comparisons.  If you don't like `toupper`, check out its sibline `tolower`.

Comment: @0x5453 Okay i still couldn't figure out how to make it work. The it->payrate that you gave me just and it's still not working due to some debugging error when i run it. Here's my updated code.

Comment: `for (; it != employees.end(); it++)
 {
  cout << "ID of employee:  \n" << it->id << ": \n" 
   << "Employees name: \n" << it->firstName << " " << it->lastName << ": \n" 
   << "Employee pay rate: \n" << it->payRate << ": \n" 
   << "Employee hours worked: \n" << it->hours << "\n";
 }

 float sum = it->payRate * it->hours;
 float avg = sum / employees.size();

 Employee e;

 cout << " ID of employees: \n" << e.id;
 cout << " Name of employees: \n" << e.firstName << " " << e.lastName;
 cout << "Gross pay of employees: \n" << avg;`

Comment: @Limitbreaker By the time you read `it`, the iterator is already past the end of the vector, which is Undefined Behavior.  Unless I misunderstand, gross pay is a per-employee stat, so it should be calculated inside of some employee loop.

Comment: @0x5453, yes you're correct. Gross pay is per-employee stat

Answer (score 0):

```
    vector<Employee> employees;

    char Another = 'y';

    while (Another == 'y' || Another == 'Y')
    {
        Employee e;
        cout << "Enter employee ID: \n";
        cin >> e.id;
        cout << "Enter employee first name: \n";
        cin >> e.firstName;
        cout << "Enter employee last name: \n";
        cin >> e.lastName;
        cout << "Enter employee pay rate: \n";
        cin >> e.payRate;
        cout << "Enter employee hours worked: \n";
        cin >> e.hours;
        employees.push_back(e);

        cout << "Another? (y/n): \n";
        cin >> Another;

    }

    float sum = 0;

    vector<Employee>::iterator it = employees.begin();

    cout << "ID" << "\t" << "First Name" << "\t" << "Last Name" << "\t" << "Pay rate" << "\t" << "Hours" << "\t" << "Gross Pay" << "\n" ;

    for (; it != employees.end(); it++)
    {
        float grossPay = it->payRate * it->hours;
        cout << it->id << "\t" << it->firstName << "\t\t" << it->lastName << "\t\t" << it->payRate << "\t\t" 
            << it->hours << "$" << "\t" << grossPay << "\n";
        sum += grossPay;
    }

    cout << "The gross pay for all employee is: " << "$" << sum;


    _getch();
    return 0;

}

//This is what i got so far. But if I want to make the application ask the user to input how many employee they want to enter into the database how do i do that? would it be like this?


int EMPLOYEE_NUM[][]    // ??
```